# Fresh Ubuntu 16.04 installation does not boot

Tags: uefi, ssd, grub-efi

I installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 on Acer Aspire E15 E5--7465 alongside pre-installed Windows 10. The installation went as usual, but when I boot the computer it takes me directly to Windows without showing the GRUB screen. I have also tried boot-repair, here is the log: http://paste2.org/bAzWDZBY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i found a solution:

1. Reboot your computer and enter BIOS settings with F2
2. Make sure secure boot is enabled and BIOS supervisor password is set
3. Go to Security tab in BIOS settings
4. Select "Select UEFI file as trusted"
5. Select HDD1
6. Select EFI
7. Select ubuntu
8. Select grubx64.efi
9. In the opened window enter "grubx64.efi" and press enter two times
10. Save BIOS settings and reboot
11. Enter BIOS settings using F2 key
12. Go to Boot tab in BIOS settings
13. Move the option "EFI File Boot 0: grubx64.efi" to the first place of the boot order
14. Save BIOS settings and reboot
15. The GRUB menu will appear and it should be possible to boot into Ubuntu

Comment: This would indeed help (even in my case). What also helped though, is disabling Secure Boot in BIOS/UEFI before booting into Ubuntu - in case one aims to install it to the hard disk(s).